# How do I access value of a selected <option> tag down 2 trees in a function?

Tags: reactjs, select, jsx

[PizzaBuilder1.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6xff.png)

[Ingredients.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wc9F.png)

[Bases.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS7oo.png)

[PizzaBuilder2.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaRaM.png)

[PizzaBuilder3.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9SZf.png)

I'll try to describe my issue in the least confusing way. So what I'm trying to achieve is create a function(pic4-PizzaBuilder2), where I compare the given key of this.state.ingredients.Bases (and other sub-objects, but that's not important for now) with value of selected option tag in Bases.js and when it matches, set the given value of that key to true. The hierarchy is like this: PizzaBuilder.js > Ingredients.js > Bases.js. I have already managed to match each option value with the key inside the object with the same name. However, what I'm still struggling with is how to access it in PizzaBuilder.js when the select option value I wanna compare it to is 2 trees down (see pic4-PizzaBuilder2, that is supposed to be const selectedOption, but I obviously still need to figure out how to access it). I'll be really grateful for any kind of advice.